# Elegant way to solve trigonometric algebraic problem

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I'm dealing with the following problem:

Known variables: $N_x, F_x, F_y$

Unknowns: $\theta, Ny$.

System of equations:

$$N_x=F_x\cos\theta+F_y\sin\theta$$

$$N_y=-F_x\sin\theta+F_y\cos\theta$$

By inspection it looks rather simple but I truly don't know how to solve it analytically.

Comment: in the first equation you reduce the RHS term to something like $A \sin(\theta+B)$ (using $F_y/F_x = \cot B$). This will give you $\theta$. The second equation will thus now give you the other component of the normal force, $N_y$.

Comment: Alternately square both and sum to get $N_y$.

Answer (score 1):

(@Macavity's idea)

Just square both statements. $$N_x^2+N_y^2=F_x^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta)+F_y^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta)=F_x^2+F_y^2$$
From this, we can find out $N_y$
Substitute in the first equation, and it becomes of the form $$a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta=c$$ which can easily be solved.